# CORS issue with AWS API Gateway in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have tried by adding interceptor but its not working

```
import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
//import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor
{
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) 
    {
        console.log("interceptor is getting called");
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

      console.log(JSON.stringify(request));

       request = request.clone({

        setHeaders: {
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'my-auth-token',
        } 
      });
      return next.handle(request).catch((error ,caught )=>{
        //intercept the respons error and displace it to the console
        console.log("Error Occurred");
        console.log(error);
        //return the error to the method that called it
        return Observable.throw(error);``
        }) as any; 
    }
}
```

Comment: CORS should be resolved by backend side not from client side, please check backend code for the same

Comment: are you using a proxy.conf.json in your angular project? 
maybe you need to add following: "changeOrigin": true

More information here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

for further help please provide more information about your setup

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server allows CORS with something like this:

"headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }